# Двойной цикл по таблице в базе Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Есть таблица в которой нужно пронумеровать повторяющиеся записи для каждой группы дубликатов отдельно, т.е.

1. 1234 1
2. 1234 2
3. 1234 3
4. 1235 1
5. 1235 2
6. ....

Создаю двойной цикл для сравнения каждой строчки таблицы с остальными.

```
Dim table As DAO.Recordset

    Dim i, j, n As Long
    Dim Pesel_1, Pesel_2 As String

    Set table = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Kopia_Dane", dbOpenTable)

    n = table.RecordCount

    For i = 0 To n - 1
       Pesel_1 = table.Fields("Pesel").Value
       For j = i + 1 To n
           Pesel_2 = table.Fields("Pesel").Value
           MsgBox Pesel_1 & " " & Pesel_2 & " i: " & i & " j: " & j
           table.Move (j)
       Next j
       table.Move (i)
    Next i
```

В итоге при прохождении 5 строчки мне выдает ошибку **3021 no current record**.
Исходная таблица в порядке. 
Самое интересное что при увеличении количества строк в таблице, количество пройденных циклом строк увеличивается. 
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: наверно в этом цЫкле )) `For j = i + 1 To n` тоже нужно `n - 1` сделать? `j` выходит за границу количества записей.

Comment: Да, выходит за границу, но не в этом дело. Если проблема была в этом то ошибка выходила бы под конец цИкла. Это не решает проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нужно пронумеровать повторяющиеся записи для каждой группы дубликатов отдельно

Для решения задачи достаточно одного цикла, будет нечто вроде:

```
Set table = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT field, group_num FROM table ORDER BY field, id", dbOpenDynaset)
current = -1
counter = 0
With table
    .Movefirst
    do until .eof
        if current = !field then
            counter = counter + 1
        else 
            counter = 1
            current = !field
        end if
        .edit
        !group_num = counter
        .update
        .movenext
    loop
    .close
end with
```